# Server will get stuck without a printf(), only works well with a printf(), super strange

Tags: c, tcp

I'm a newer and just began to learn Data Network which is about TCP/IP, client and server.

I'm writing a program for server trying to read data from client(Coming from user input using `scanf()`). But the strangest thing is:

The server will get stuck at `read()` function.

However, when I put a `printf()` function after the `read()` function, it didn't get stuck! But I believe that `printf()` actually did nothing to the code running. It drives me crazy and I can't understand this...

Simple code are here:

```
simpleChildSocket = accept(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName,&clientNameLength);
if (simpleChildSocket == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot accept connections!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
    exit(1);
}

//read data 
returnStatus = read(simpleChildSocket, username, sizeof(username));
printf("Received username: %s\n", username); //*That's where strange happens*

if(returnStatus > 0){
    printf("Yes");
}
else{
    printf("No");
    close(simpleChildSocket);
}
```

Comment: It isn't valid to print `username` unless `read()` returned a positive value.

Comment: There are too many things not shown here. Like `simpleSocket`, `clientNameLength`, `username`. How are they defined and initialized?

Comment: Amongst ofther things, it's likely that 'printf("%s...) is called on a char array which is not guaranteed NUL terminated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `printf` inside the `if` do not print any `\n`, so output is buffered but not flushed. Adding  the `printf` after the read does contains a `\n` this is why you can see the output, but the code behave exactly the same in both cases.

Change `print("Yes")` to `printf("Yes\n")` and similarly for `"No"`.